# How to find hours passed since given time in millseconds in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

One of the tool gives the start time in milliseconds as below:

`'StartMilliseconds': 1645250400857`

How do I find the hours passed since this timestamp? I tried below

```
   >>> start=datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1645250400857/1000.0)
   >>> now=datetime.datetime.now
   >>> now-start
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 
   'datetime.datetime'
```

Comment: `datetime.datetime.now` is a _function_. You need to actually call the function to get the current time. `now=datetime.datetime.now()`

Answer (score 0):

You can find the current timestamp in seconds using `datetime.now().timestamp()` and then apply the conversions to compute hours since start:

```
from datetime import datetime

start_ms = 1645250400857

hours_since_start = (datetime.now().timestamp() - start_ms / 1000) / 3600
```